# Syntax error in FROM clause Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, syntax-error, runtime-error

Here is my code to retrieve data from access but I always encounter "Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)' Syntax error in FROM clause"

```
Sub UPDATE_REGION()
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim AW As Workbook
Set AW = ActiveWorkbook
Path = AW.Path
cnn_pth = Path & "\Master File.accdb"
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
With cnn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .Open cnn_pth
End With
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
sSQL = "select Package_Nb from [package_db] where [Hubs] is null"
rst.Open Source:=sSQL, ActiveConnection:=cnn, CursorType:=adOpenForwardOnly, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, Options:=adCmdTable
end subs
```

When i stop script to debug, I found Source value in Local Window like this: `"select * from select Package_Nb from package_db where Hubs is null"`

I don't know why vba auto add `select * from` to source like this, anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options are wrong. This:

```
Options:=adCmdTable
```

should be this:

```
Options:=adCmdText
```

Since you are not passing a table name but a SQL string. (when you pass a table name it is effectively converted into a `SELECT * FROM table_name` statement).

Comment: Tks so much for prompt answer