# Syntax error in FROM clause Excel VBA in rs.open

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to import a dataset from access to excel via a macro. I'm getting the above mentioned error in the line where it's opening the record set. Trying hard to resolve but with no success. Found this question ([Syntax error in FROM clause Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451358/syntax-error-in-from-clause-excel-vba)) but its answer isn't solving my problem. Kindly help out.

```
Sub importAccessdata()

    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Dim sQRY As String


    Dim strFilePath As String

    strFilePath = "Path"

    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset


    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & strFilePath & ";"

    sQRY = "select * from tableName"


    With rs
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient

        .Open Source:=sQRY, ActiveConnection:=cnn,CursorType:=adOpenForwardOnly, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, Options:=adCmdText
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(“A1”).CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close

    Set rs = Nothing

    cnn.Close

    Set cnn = Nothing

    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: is `tableName` a table that exists?

Comment: Same as Nathan: Is "Path" a valid path?

Comment: Yes, both Path and tableName are valid. I checked.

Comment: did you try your select in acces itself? if you try to debug and go step by step, on what line do you get an error?

Comment: Assuming `Path` is a valid filename (a file without extension!) and it's on the current path (however that is determined), it should probably work - otherwise the code would blow up already at `cnn.Open`.

Comment: Code is running for me. In case of wrong path or tablename you get different error messages. The only way to generate an error message similar to the mentioned one was: I inserted a white space into `sQRY`

Comment: Hi @Inarion- if I try without the file extension, in the cnn.open line its showing "Could not find file". If possible please give an example of value to go in strFilePath variable.

Comment: Huh, you literally have `Path` in there as the complete path to the file. And we were wondering how that would ever work. Now it seems you just replaced `C:\Your\true\path\to\your\database.accdb` with `Path`? I'm confused. But as long as it doesn't error out for you, it has to be working.

Comment: you're one of those people who call their dogs, just dog? (instead of giving it a name)  ;)